# Does kops 1.22+ allow to assign a custom IAM role to a kubernetes node?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, roles

I'm using kops 1.22.6 to add a new node to my k8s cluster
(working with AWS).

The new node should optimally use the custom IAM role, unlike the generic IAM roles that kops created for the rest of the cluster nodes.

However, the same yaml which worked perfectly well with kops 1.16 fails to deliver the same result with the last kops version(1.22.6)
Previously this worked just fine :

```
     iam:
        profile: arn:aws:iam::1111111:instance-profile/my-custom-role
```

Now I keep getting the error below. The switching of ec2 to the generic role resolves the error but defeats the purpose of having the custom role. Any suggestions?

```
Oct 14 10:12:58 ip-10-103-71-131 nodeup[14374]: I1014 10:12:58.590007  14374 executor.go:186] Executing task “BootstrapClientTask/BootstrapClient”: BootstrapClientTask
Oct 14 10:12:58 ip-10-103-71-131 nodeup[14374]: W1014 10:12:58.617887  14374 executor.go:139] error running task “BootstrapClientTask/BootstrapClient” (5m50s remaining to succeed): bootstrap returned status code 403:  
 failed to verify token: arn “arn:aws:sts::1111111:assumed-role/my-custom-role/i-01463a31fc9ac51b2”. 
 does not contain acceptable node role
```